# How to prevent from download of file, taking screenshot and sharing option from the web browser in Angular

Tags: angular, download

I want to give only view option of opened pdf, image, file. User should not download, share and take screenshot from the web browser. I want to implement this functionality in the Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two answers:

[How can I disable print-screen functionality for a webpage in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938466/how-can-i-disable-print-screen-functionality-for-a-webpage-in-all-browsers)

[How do i prevent from printscreen of my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427286/how-do-i-prevent-from-printscreen-of-my-webpage)

In a native Android/iOS app you can catch this behaviour but in the browser you can't.

**What you could do** is to prevent text selection:
[Disable text selection with Angular directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066819/disable-text-selection-with-angular-directive)